# python: create iterator through subsets of a set for a loop

Tags: python

I have a sequence of consecutive integers, for example `[1, 2, 3]`. I'd like to create an iterator that goes through all the subsets of the set. In this case `[], [1],...,[1,2,3]`. How could I do this?

Answer (score 14):

The [`itertools` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#recipes) contains a recipe for this construction under the name `powerset`, if that's what you need.

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another simple way of doing that without extra libraries

```py
set = [1,2,3]
subsets = [[]]

for el in set:
    for i in range(len(subsets)):
        subsets += [subsets[i]+[el]]

print(subsets)
```

The output:

```
[[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

---

Or even simpler with the help of list comprehension

```py
set = [1,2,3]
subsets = [[]]

for el in set:
    subsets += [s+[el] for s in subsets]

print(subsets)
```